# Regex to match content between given characters

Tags: regex

What is need is given the following string "*Other Text [[MyText]] Some Other Text*", and given some specific characters like "[[" for start and "]]" for end, to be able to match "[[MyText]]".

Given the following `regex = "(\[\[)(.*)(\]\])"` I am able to match what I want, but not exactly.

Lets say I have this string "Other Text[[ Something...[[MyText]]......something...[[MyOtherText]]" - I need to have 2 matches here "[[MyText]]" && "[[MyOtherText]]". My regex is too eager and matches more than I really want to.

Please, besides the answer I am looking to understand how it works, so a few comments as well will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [non-greedy pattern](http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001) or '[perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)'.

```
(\[\[)(.*?)(\]\])
```

Note that additional '?' character;

Comment: That worked. I should really stop using Visual Studio Find dialog to test my regex expressions, as I tried that, and Studio found nothing!

Comment: @mouviciel: what was happening before was that a single regex was grabbing all the material from the first '[[' to the second ']]'.  As fixed, the regex only grabs the material between the first '[[' and the first ']]', allowing a second pass starting after the ']]' to grab the second '[[...stuff...]]' phrase.

Comment: @Ivan: as far as Visual Studio goes, avoid it like the plague with regular expressions. The designers decided to use their own non-standard set of regexes. It's not even the flavor that the .NET runtime uses: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this :

```
regex = "\[\[([^\[]*)\]\]"
```

It will will blow up if you have a '[' in your text your trying to match, or nested pairs.

The reason it works this way is the default [greedy matching](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Greedy.html) of most regex implementations.  In short greedy matching is taking as much as the match could possibly cover.  The reason my regex works is that it does not allow another "[" (so it can't greedy match into the next set).  Enjoy your wiki work.

Comment: Looks dubious to me - the catcher clause matches zero or more open square brackets (after the initial two).  That wasn't in the question.

Comment: That regex will match "[[]]", "[[[[[[[[]]", etc. Not "[[MyText]]". You probably meant "\[\[[^\]]*\]\]"

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, Bart, I forgot the all important ^.

Comment: @C.Rohss :D - the caret as written in `\[\[(^\[*)\]\]` only matches itself.  You might be thinking of a negated character class: `\[\[([^]]*)\]\]`, but that disallows '[[abc[def]ghi]]' which should be matched.  The non-greedy regex ('`.*?`') is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Jonathan: Right (and sorry about the h), fixed the [^\\[] issue.  The non-greedy regex is probably a better solution in the long term, if nothing else but for readability.  Is ? as a non-greedy symbol supported by most implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\[{2}(?:(?!]]).)*]]
```

Also works with single ['s and ]'s inside your double [[ and ]]'s.

For a good explanation, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Note that ] is not a meta character (outside a character class), so there's no real need to escape it.